# Socket.io / Nodejs is failing sending a data from the server after a several hours of running

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, openshift

Guys i have a problem . I have this application that use **Socket.io** for realtime getting data that send every minute to client side and i use mongodb as a database , and **Nodejs** for handling the server and my hosting is **Openshift** . At 1-7 hours my application is running smoothly but after a few hours some data didn't save to my data base .

## Thing's that i try.

- See the log's in open shift.
- Re-check my server code's.
- Upgrade My Memory in **Open Shift**

### Error That seem's matter

- I don't have Favicon , Sometime it send error , in my console log.
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Any idea what is causing to this problem  ?